# Динамическое изменение контента мета-тега property:"og:image"

Tags: php

В фейсбуке все делается только через мета теги.
Делаю розыгрыш, в котором пользователь загружает картинку, потом авторизуется, давая нам данные, и делает перепост. Вот эту картинку он и должен перепостить.

Вопрос: Как лучше менять мета тег картинки для перепоста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[property="og:image"]').attr('content','image.jpg');
```

Как-то так наверное

Comment: Так не меняется ничего.

Comment: Через jquery Было бы лучше всего, но не работает почему-то.

Comment: $('.bond-slide img').mouseover(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  $('.popup-image img').attr("src", src);
  $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content", src);
 });  Вот так не работает. МОжет у меня ошибка

Comment: Есть какие-то ошибки?

Comment: Нету ошибок просто не работает

Comment: Что выводит:
`console.log($('[property="og:image"]')); `
?

Comment: С удовольствием скажу если скажите куда эту штуку вставить и где посмотреть. Уровень знаний говорит сам за себя. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вставьте эту штуку в скрипт, потом откройте браузер->исходный код страницы->консоль. Или проверьте есть ли у вас на странице тег 
`<meta content="image.jpg" property="og:image">`

Comment: В консоли выдает воттакую штуковину: Object { 0: <meta>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → hungryduck.com.ua, selector: "[property="og:image"]" }

Comment: Еще вот такую Этот сайт использует сертификат SHA-1; рекомендуется использовать сертификаты с алгоритмами подписи, использующими более сильные хеш-функции, чем SHA-1.

Comment: Я запускаю
`$('.bond-slide img').mouseover(function(){ var src = $(this).attr("src"); $('.popup-image img').attr("src", src); $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content", src); });`
через консоль браузера. При наводке на фото, тег `<meta content="image.jpg" property="og:image">` меняется. Как вы проверяете код на работоспособность?

Comment: открыл консоль "sourses" в хроме навожу на картинки и смотрю на метатег. Он не меняется у меня. Контент пустой изначально идет . И в нем ничего не добавляется. Может в этом дело?

Comment: Только что проверил. На вашем сайте: http://hungryduck.com.ua/ всё работает.

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте пожалуйста его как правильный

Comment: Пока не помог, Вопрос остается открытым так как при попытке росшарить все равно выдает не тот файл. У вас тот выдает? Если да то конечно отмечу

Comment: Данные из мета тегов для росшаривания берутся при загрузке страницы. Если их менять, то никакого эффекта это не принесёт. Все равно в форме поделится будет самое первое изображение.

Comment: Так же социальные сети кешируют данные мета-тегов, поэтому при частой смене значения атрибута могут возникнуть ошибки. Для очистки кеша существуют специальные инструменты:
[VK](http://vk.com/dev/pages.clearCache)
[FB](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы сохраняете ссылки на изображения на своем сервере, Вы можете давать пользователю ссылку вида `some-page?id=id_изображения` для шэринга а на сервере подтягивать url изображения из GET параметра и подставлять его в `og:image`

PS. JavaScript не работает т.к. для парсинга тега `og:image` к Вам на сайт приходит бот фэйсбука, а он вряд ли выполняет JS.